# How to solve CSS include error after Apache RewriteRule?

Tags: css, apache, url-rewriting, localhost

I use winXP and AppServ. I have a "showitem.php" on my website root. An example usage: 
    `www.mydomain.com/showitem.php?id=123`
I want to use links like following:
    `www.mydomain.com/item/123`
In .htaccess I write this line:
    `RewriteRule ^item/([^/]+)$ showitem.php?id=$1`

Server directs to showitem.php and id is received successfully. However, main problem is with the css and js files. If I make "css/style.css" to "/css/style.css", page is shown on the internet and but not on localhost, because root is "localhost" but files are under "localhost/mydomain". I have also tried "!-f" condition for .css files but it doesn't help and it can't as far as I understand. To solve the problem, I should direct wrong css file interpretation to the correct place, so I want to redirect client request "item/css/style.css" to its original location "css/style.css". I add the following rules for localhost but is there any other way?

```
RewriteRule ^item/css/([^/]+)$ /mydomain/css/$1
RewriteRule ^item/img/([^/]+)$ /mydomain/img/$1
```

Answer (score 1):

Set a base tag in your html head.

`<base href="http://www.mydomain.com/" />`

And then set your stylesheet linking paths relative to the base, e.g.

`<link href="css/style.css" />`

Comment: Since I am developing css, js and php at the same time and since they are on my localhost, this is not practical for me.

Comment: why should this be unpractical? set it to `http://localhost/`. I just took the data from your example.

Answer (score 0):

you could write these to the file `.htaccess`

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error_404.php
```

`/error_404.php` is your error file you want to put something in there.